# Change the Input Text Value Passed through JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I could use a little help. I've loaded the objects in an array that I've made in PHP into a bunch of input boxes. The objects are for a shopping cart: price, quantity, and total price respectively. While the data loads up fine, it seems to be read-only.

For example, the input text value for quantity says 1, and I can't change it.

I want to be able change the quantity without having to go back to my MySQL table.

I can do it just fine with regular Ajax, but when I use regular Ajax, the item won't load without refreshing like all of my other ajax functions.

Here's the code.

```
   function updates(){ 
         $.getJSON("classes/cartlist.php", function(data) {

         $("#cart_list, #cart_table").empty(); 
            $.each(data.result, function(){ $("#cart_list, #cart_table").append(
                   "<tr id='"+this['id']+"'> 
                         <td> "+this['pro_title']+" </td> 
                         <td> <input type='text' id='price-"+this["p_id"]+
                                "' class='price' pid='"+this["p_id"]+
                                "'value='"+this["price"]+"' /> 
                        </td>
                   </tr> "); 
                 }); 
            });
```

This isn't everything but the two other input boxes are just the same thing. I figured this'd be easier to read if I left it like this.

EDIT: Here's what the quantity input text box looks like, since someone asked.

```
<td><input type='text' id='qty-"+this["p_id"]+"' class='qty' pid='"+this["p_id"]+"' value='"+this["qty"]+"' />
```

EDIT: Okay so I've found the reason I can't change the text and that is the set interval function that is going with the JSON

```
  function done() {
            setTimeOut (
               function(){
                updates();
                }, 300)
             }
```

But if I get rid of that I'll have to refresh the page to get my data back..

Comment: where is your quantity field?

Comment: can you show the structure of json

Comment: Ah.. I'm not sure what you mean.. Sorry, I'm kinda new to JSON..

Answer (score 0):

i think there is an error in append string to

```
function updates(){ 
     $.getJSON("classes/cartlist.php", function(data) {

     $("#cart_list, #cart_table").empty();
        //make use of index and value inside function 
        $.each(data.result, function(index,value){ 
            // here some thing with your code because \n indicate the end of statement so  
            $("#cart_list, #cart_table").append(
               "<tr id='"+this['id']+"'>" + 
                     "<td> "+this['pro_title']+" </td> "+
                     "<td> <input type='text' id='price-"+this["p_id"]+
                            "' class='price' pid='"+this["p_id"]+
                            "' value='"+this["price"]+"' />"+ 
                    "</td>"+
               "</tr> "); 
             }); 
        });
```

Comment: It's not working. The appending part's working perfectly already, but I just can't change the text in the resulting input text boxes.